# Emacs 23 with python.el not able to keep up with typing and renders screen with a delay

Tags: python, emacs

I am currently using python.el that by default gets shipped with Emacs 23.

I can notice that when i am editing python files, the screen update happens in bursts. e.g. I hold a key, nothing happens in screen, and every 1 seconds or 2 they appear.

Also the problem happens only with editing python files. other modes like clojure-mode etc doesn't have this problem.

And I noticed that when i switched to python-mode.el, the problem seems to have gone, and the typing is smooth.

However I would like to user python.el hence is there a way, I can get away this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably do best to use the [new python mode](https://github.com/fgallina/python.el) instead of those two you mention. I haven't used them, but I've used the new one and it's pretty decent. There is also the fact that its maintainer has stepped up to maintain the old python.el mode and will replace it internally by the new one anyways.(or at least this was the plan when I last read on the topic in the Emacs mailing list a couple of months ago).